# Button over ImageView Android

Tags: android, button, layout, imageview, android-imageview

I'm developing a game which consist to find someone's head which is hidden in front of a lot heads.
To Recognize him , i have to zoom on the ImageView.

I Tried to put a button over the imageview.
But when i zoom on the imageView , the button stay at the same place so i can't associate it with the head.

This the button's code

```
        public void onClick(View v) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(JeuActivity.this, GameActivity.class);

            intent.putExtra("result" , counter);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

What is the Solution ?
Thank you.

Comment: You need to add more code, this question doesn't have enough information

Answer (score 0):

Why use a button at all?  You can put a click handler on the image view directly.

Comment: I don't want to click on all the ImageView.

I want to click on only one head because in the ImageView there are a lot of heads and i have to find the head which i have to find.

Thank you

Comment: Then I'd suggest a custom touch handler, which can scale locations with your matrix for the zoom.  A button is never going to work well.

Answer (score 0):

Button, and ImageView both extend View.

The setOnClickListener is a method on View, which means you can just apply a click handler directly to your ImageView (and not have a button at all).

See this:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html

Comment: I don't want to click on all the ImageView.

I want to click on only one head because in the ImageView there are a lot of heads and i have to find the head which i have to find.

Thank you